# FactoryBoy is accessing normal DB instead of TEST DB

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-testing, factory-boy

I'm trying to create some objects in `setUp` method of Django test case. I use `FactoryBoy` that helps me with creating the objects. But it seems that `FactoryBoy` can't find any objects in the database.

factories.py

```
class ProductFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    ...
    market_category = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(list(MarketplaceCategory.objects.all()))

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from marketplaces.models import MarketplaceCategory

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        ...
        self.marketplace_category = MarketplaceCategoryFactory.create()
        print(MarketplaceCategory.objects.first().pk) # prints 1
        self.product = ProductFactory(created_by=self.user)
```

As you can see, `ProductFactory` tries to populate `Product.market_category` by random `MarketCategory` object.

The problem is that it seems like it does not exist even when I've created it before and made sure it is in the db (it has `pk`).

EDIT: It chose a `MarketCategory` object with pk=25 but there is only one such objects in the test db with pk=1. I think it accesses Django development DB instead of testing one.

The error:

```
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "products_product" violates foreign key constraint "products_product_market_category_id_2d634517_fk"
DETAIL:  Key (market_category_id)=(25) is not present in table "marketplaces_marketplacecategory".
```

Do you have any idea why it behaves this way? It looks like the `Factory` is accessing the real `DB` instead of `testdb` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the "market_category" field like that is going to cause issues, the queryset that populates the choices is going to be executed at some random time whenever the module is imported and the instances returned may no longer exist. You should use a [SubFactory](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.SubFactory)

```
class ProductFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    
    market_category = factory.SubFactory(MarketplaceCategoryFactory)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

Pass the queryset directly to [`FuzzyChoice`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fuzzy.html#factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice) to get a random existing value, don't convert it to a list

```
class ProductFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    
    market_category = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(MarketplaceCategory.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

This will then create an instance whenever you create a product but you can pass "market_category" to the factory to override it

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.marketplace_category = MarketplaceCategoryFactory.create()
        self.product = ProductFactory(created_by=self.user, market_category =self.marketplace_category)
```

Comment: Iain thanks but what if I want to choose a random object?

Comment: @Milano pass the queryset directly to FuzzyChoice, don't convert it to a list. Example above